# Prove or disprove this proposition:

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers, then $pq+1$ is prime. 
I don't really know how this can be proven, I've used prime numbers to plug in but I don't know how the steps should go.

Comment: Odd times odd is ...

Comment: Even 3 times 3 =6

Comment: That's a good one!  But seriously...

Comment: This is almost always false, because if $p$ and $q$ are odd, then $pq+1$ is even

Comment: So how this can be proven tho Ik its

Comment: How can a false statement be proven? Are you kidding?

Comment: The most common case (both primes odd) is known.  If $p$ is even and $q$ is odd, *nothing* can be concluded, for example, i) $(p,q) = (2,3)$ so $pq + 1 = 7$ is prime  ii) $(p,q) = (2,7)$ so $pq = 15$.  The last case $p = q = 2$ is trivial.

Comment: False. For example, $3*5+ 1 = 16$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion is false, as a (counter) example: $p = 5, q = 7$ are both primes, yet $pq +1 = 5\cdot 7 +1 = 36$ is a composite ! and in general, $pq+1$ is even and $ > 2$, thus can *never* be a prime.

Comment: So how this can be proven tho? Ik it's false

Comment: The proof that it's false is that @Deepsea gave a counterexample.

Comment: Ya I know got it

Answer (score 1):

Let $p=13$ and $q=17$. So you have $$pq+1\equiv_3 1*2+1\equiv_3 0$$, so it's divisible by $3$, and clearly it's greater than $3$, so $pq+1$ is composite.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers $3$ and $7$ are primes, but $3\cdot7+1 = 22 = 2\cdot 11$ is not, hence the proposition is false.